# How to write an object into another while returning as a response of REST API?

Tags: java, rest, api, jpa, httpresponse

I have two  classes `address` & `customer` with `toString()` method. customer & address are in one-to-one mapping. So, every customer contains an address. Let's look at the following ...

> **I would like to have a http response as:-**

```
{
    "id": customerId,
    "addressId": addressId,
    "firstName": "first_name",
    "lastName": "last_name",
    "address": {
         "id": addressId,
         "street": "street",
         "city": "city",
         "country": "country",
         "postalCode": "postal_code"
    } 
}
```

> **Address.java**

```
package com.maxpro.models;

import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
public class Address {

    private Long id;
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String country;
    private String postalCode;

    // getters & setters

    @Override
    public String toString () {
        return String.format("address[id='%d', street='%s', city='%s', country='%s', postalCode='%s']",
                                      id, street, city, country, postalCode
        );
    }

}
```

> **Customer.java**

```
package com.maxpro.models;

import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
public class Customer {

    private Long id;
    private Long addressId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    private Address address;

    // getters & setters
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "customer[id=%d, addressId=%d, firstName='%s', lastName='%s', address='%s']",
                             id, addressId, firstName, lastName, address
        );
    }

}
```

> **CustomerRestController.java**

```
package com.maxpro.controllers.rest;

import com.maxpro.models.Address;
import com.maxpro.models.Customer;
import com.maxpro.repositories.AddressRepository;
import com.maxpro.repositories.CustomerRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/customers")
public class CustomerRestController {

    // CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long>
    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    // AddressRepository extends CrudRepository<Address, Long>
    @Autowired
    private AddressRepository addressRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/customer-with-address/{customerId}")
    public Customer getCustomerWithAddress(@PathVariable("customerId") Long customerId) {
        return customerRepository.findOne(customerId);
    }

}
```

> It shows:

```
Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.maxpro.models.Customer["address"]->com.maxpro.models.Address_$$_jvst556_1["handler"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.maxpro.models.Customer["address"]->com.maxpro.models.Address_$$_jvst556_1["handler"])
```

**How do I get the expected result? That means, how do I put `address` object into `customer` in HTTP response?**

Comment: What does `CustomerRepository` do? As far as we can tell, `customerRepository.findOne` should grab a customer object, which already has the Address field.

Comment: CustomerReposity extends findOne() of CrudRepository which picks a customer by `cutomerId` @cricket_007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to eagerly fetch child ie Address for the Customer. Since you are using JPA, there should be a relation between the two entity. It can be either One-to-Many or One-to-One..

Decide on the relationship you want to maintain between the two entity and just specify fetch type. 
e.g: `@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`

Comment: It shows -> Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException -- @user1211

Comment: I also tried with --- `public class Customer implements Serializable` --- @user1211

Comment: Where have u added the annotation? Read an example.. https://hellokoding.com/jpa-one-to-many-relationship-mapping-example-with-spring-boot-maven-and-mysql/

Comment: Was there any issue to be fixed with Address serializeableness?